# Import a library/dependency with Laravel Mix

Tags: npm, laravel-mix

I have a small problem that took some time to find a solution. I'm trying to import this library to my project in Laravel.

https://www.adchsm.com/slidebars/help/usage/initializing-slidebars/

I have installed the library with NPM.

`npm install slidebars --save-dev`

Then I'm trying to import this library to my `app.js` file which has the following structure:

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
import popper from "popper.js";

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
    window.Popper = popper.default;

    require('bootstrap');
    require('slidebars');

} catch (exception) {
    console.log(exception);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    let constructor = new slidebars();
});
```

run `npm run watch` but then in my browser I get the following error in the console:

`ReferenceError: slidebars is not defined`

Please, if you could help me, I have searched in different places, but I can not find a solution for it. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run...

```
npm install slidebars

+ slidebars@2.0.2
added 1 package and audited 16905 packages in 9.487s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

In /resources/js/app.js add...

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.slidebars = require('slidebars');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Then compile the assets:

```
npm run prod
```