# Importing a library to laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to import [this library](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) to my laravel project.

My laravel project is setup [with vessel.](https://vessel.shippingdocker.com)

I tried the answer on [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696234/import-a-library-dependency-with-laravel-mix) like this :

```
resources/js/app.js
------------------- 
    window.tagify = require('@yaireo/tagify');
```

and this is my view:

```
 <input value='[{"value":"foo", "editable":false}, {"value":"bar"}]'>

                <script>

                    var inputElement = document.querySelector('input')
                    new Tagify(inputElement)

                </script>
```

But I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Tagify is not defined
```

Perhaps anyone has a clue what else I could try to make this work.

Comment: I get this with Tagify and Laravel 9 too. Did you ever find the solution?